# php equivalent of python lxlm.etree fromstring

Tags: php, python, xml

I'm fairly new to python and I'm re-writing a python script that accesses an API.

In the python script, I'm trying to find the equivalient of this:

```
response = get_resource(url, auth=(username,password), params=params)
return lxml.etree.fromstring(response.content)
```

returns <http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom} feed at 0x2f12b70>

What is the equivalent of this code in php? And I'm not even sure what this is returning?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this kind of question is that it can only be answered by someone with expertise in both systems. There are actually two questions here: first, what is lxml.etree.fromstring doing (which you can probably look up in the docs); secondly, once you know what you're trying to achieve, how can you achieve it with PHP? My guess is that this is returning a Python object of some sort, which will then be used in various ways; as such, there won't be a 1-to-1 correspondence to PHP, though since XML is mentioned, you might want to read up on [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml).

Comment: Thanks IMSoP. I've looked extensively through SimpleXML but haven't had much luck. Will check again.